# Can a child process generated by "fork()" ever have a process id lesser than its parent?

Tags: c, linux, fork, fedora, pid

Can a child process generated by `fork()` ever have a process id lesser than its parent(without crossing the maximum limit)?

The PID is usually the next available value but anyhow can it possibly be less than the parent's PID?

Comment: Suppose the maximum possible PID on a system is, say, 32767 (the argument is the same for any arbitrary maximum value). Suppose process 32767 calls `fork()`. What can we say about the PID of the newly created child process?

Comment: The counter will reset and then new PIDs will be assigned from 0, but why the next number, why not the least availabe id(as we have in case of assigning file descriptors)

Comment: I don't know that there's any standard about how PIDs are assigned. Assigning either the next sequential number that hasn't yet been assigned, or the lowest number that hasn't been assigned, would be perfectly legitimate, as long as all PIDs for currently running processes are unique. There's probably some advantage in letting PIDs for dead processes "lie fallow" for as long as possible. My point is that if process 32767 calls `fork()`, the PID of the child process *must* be less than the PID of the parent process.

Comment: "*I know the new PID is always the next available value*" -- How do you know that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  PIDs are not guaranteed to be in any order.  Some systems and some security extensions generate random PIDs to avoid attacks based on child PID prediction.  Of course even systems that linearly generate PIDs need to wrap around at some point.

Comment: So that means there is no specific rule to assign a process ID?

Comment: Yes, that's what random means.  The only thing you can say is that a PID will be some positive integer of type `pid_t` which is unique among all the processes currently running.  You cannot say it is larger or smaller than the parent PID.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. PIDs are reused, and on some systems, PIDs do not necessarily increase monotonically.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the PIDs are reused after crossing the maximum limit (which depends on the OS and possibly configuration). So it's definitely possible provided the system is starting processes frequently enough.

Comment: I meant without crossing the limit, like we have in file descriptors where always the least available descriptor is assigned whereas in case of process id we always get an id greater than the process that generates it

Comment: @imdad: If you meant without crossing the limit, I suggest you update your question to say so.